# how to add more specificity to css class .background-color-blue so it overrides default div's background color

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS class

```
.background-color-blue {
    background-color: #00C0FF;
}
```

and I want to be able to use it on some elements if needed.

I now it is not very semantic, but it is used for HTML template that is meant to be easy to use, small in size, and universal.

I want to be able to use it on elements like some panels, sidebars, modals, top-bar menu , or whatever I want

of course it works, but only for divs that do not have background-color already specified.

in this case:

```
<div class="modal background-color-blue"></div>
```

.modal has already specified bg color to #fff. now it does not work - it stays white.

I have found two solutions for that:

```
.background-color-blue {
    background-color: #00C0FF !important;
}
```

and

```
div.background-color-blue {
    background-color: #00C0FF;
}
```

I am not sure about these... which solution is better? Or is there any other solution that would work better?

I think this method:

```
.modal.background-color-blue {
    background-color: #00C0FF;
}
```

is not good since I would have to do it with any similar element.

and

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="background-color-blue">

    </div>
</div>
```

also isn't good since modal already has some padding.

Comment: What is the problem of using: .modal.background-color-blue {
    background-color: #00C0FF;
}

Comment: Can't get you clearly, Share your code.

Comment: @LuísFerreira  it could work, but selectors would be too long for example: `.background-color-blue, .modal.background-color-blue, .top-bar.background-color-blue , .whatever.background-color-blue { background-color: #00C0FF; }` it is for html template, so should be more universal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `!important` it will help to override

```
   .background-color-blue {
    background-color: #00C0FF !important;
}
```

Take a look at this : [**when-using-important-is-the-right-choice**](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: i also think that !important makes sense in this situation, however i was not sure, because it is considered bad practice according to MDN

Answer (score 1):

If you think that modal will be able to have different colors, i guess you'd like this (ITCSS - BEM inspired). This will help you to stay at a low specificity rate, preventing you to have some problems with future classes or have to overwrite them.

Exemple here : 
http://codepen.io/AxelCardinaels/pen/ZGVKzp

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal modal--grey">
    <h1 class="modal__title"> Modal Title</h1>
    <p class="modal__text">Hello this is the content of the modal !</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
/*Base Class */

.modal{
  width:40%;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(1,1,1,0.3);
}

/*Attribute classes for the modal, just make a choice in your HTML ! */

.modal--grey{
  background:rgb(220,220,220);
  border:1px solid rgb(200,200,200);

}

.modal--blue{
  background:rgb(65,105,225);
  border:1px solid rgb(58,95,205);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper usage is

```
! important
```

Normally it should have been blue background. Perhaps something else that is preventing the elements of blue.

But don't forget that; the last !important taken into account.

Comment: i tried to find out what is preventing it, and the problem is where it is declared in css. if .background-color-blue is declared before .modal, modal stays white. otherwise it is blue. so that may be another solution to my problem: put .background-color-blue on the end of my CSS file. but relying on where it is being declared in css seems like not a good practice to me - however i dont really know...